# Matplotlib: can you change the relative height of rows using subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a multi-panel plot that looks like this

[image: multi-panel figure]

Code:

```py
f = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.subplot(211)
plt.subplot(245)
plt.subplot(246)
plt.subplot(247)
plt.subplot(248)
```

I want to keep this layout, but to make the top row take up a larger proportion of the figure. How would I go about making the top tow take up 2/3 of the figure height and the bottom row take up 1/3 of the figure height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to go about it, most of them are detailed in [Customizing Figure Layouts Using GridSpec and Other Functions](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html#customizing-figure-layouts-using-gridspec-and-other-functions)

Here is a demonstration using `GridSpec`

```
gs0 = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(2,4, height_ratios=[2,1])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0,:])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1,0])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1,1])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1,2])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1,3])
```

[image]